# MS Access - Criteria being added to a Query after the Query has run

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm new to Microsoft Access, I have created a Database to store data in relation to workers and their expertise in specific tasks, the industries they cover and the Geographic area they work in.

I'm creating a query that links to a form where the individual can choose an industry, geographic area, and area of expertise to find any workers that fit the criteria. [The example Form can be viewed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c37S8.png)

My Query design can be seen in the following [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPm5O.png)

- The Criteria i am using for each of the Expertise, Area and Industry Name fields is (obviously changed for each field) `[Forms]![Form1]![Area of Expertise Name] Or [Forms]![Form1]![Area of Expertise Name] Is Null`
- The Expertise, GeoCoverage and IndustryCoverage Fields are all Yes/No Fields so therefore I have a criteria of Yes

When I run this Query the first time it provides me the results I expect, e.g. the correct workers are provided. The issue I have is after I run the query once the criteria on the query changes and from any further runs of the query does not provide the expected result.

How the query looks after running the first time is shown in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXlmm.png)

- Note the addition of the extra criteria and the 3 weird additional fields at the end

I am unsure why this is occurring and cannot seem to work it out.

Comment: What is the OR condition on expertise name? Remove the null part. If it’s not selected, it should not filter the query anyway.

Comment: When I remove the Null part the query and run a query where one or two of the criterion empty on the form the query finds 0 records, even though I know it should be finding certain records. After having this problem and researching I added the Null part to the query. Is the Null part causing the issues with the extra criteria in the OP.